# Scrolling by increments

Tags: vb.net

I've build a usercontrol which uses a winform panel as a scrollable container for some controls.
Some of the controls serves as a header, like columns in excel.
I would like to have the same behavior on scrolling, where a fixed minimum scroll is a column width.

This works well with smallchange and LargeChange properly set, but not if I drag the scrollbar (ScrollEventType.ThumbTrack).

As there is no BeforeScroll event, I can't trap the scrolling event to modify it.
I would like to avoid a double rendering forced by a second scrolling to the desired position.

Any advice ?

Comment: Put the Controls the *serve as a header* inside another container, outside the scrolling panel. E.g., a TableLayoutPanel with one Column and two Rows: one Row used as *header* and another used as the container for the scrolling Panel.

Comment: I did not precise that my header is composed of 2 rows, and only the bottom one should act as visibly fixed. Anyway, I will give a try to your suggestion.